# Windows console aliases in any cmd.exe? Is it possible?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, console, alias

Thanks to similar questions, i figured out how to use aliases in Windows.
I created *.bat file with content:

```
DOSKEY tf=npm run testCucumberFirefox
DOSKEY tc=npm run testCucumberChrome
DOSKEY tie=npm run testCucumberIE
```

Puted it in

```
C:\Users\"User"\AppData\
```

Added new task administrative task - execute this file on log on, but then after launching any cmd.exe, these **commands are unknown**.

If i executed this file in current cmd.exe, then commands are avaliable. Is there any chance to make these commands **"public"** to any cmd.exe instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are locally defined in the console instance. Of course, they don't work if you "install" them from task.

You have to run your script in every cmd.exe instance to make aliases available. Do it by either `/k` switch, or adding your script to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` key `Autorun` value.